# how to use dataframe info to Seperate different types of column in different list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
LoanStats_securev1_2018Q1.info(verbose=True)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 107866 entries, 0 to 107865
Data columns (total 151 columns):
id                                            object
member_id                                     float64
loan_amnt                                     float64
funded_amnt                                   float64
funded_amnt_inv                               float64
term                                          object
int_rate                                      object
installment                                   float64
grade                                         object
sub_grade                                     object
emp_title                                     object
emp_length                                    object
home_ownership                                object
...
settlement_status                             object
settlement_date                               object
settlement_amount                             float64
settlement_percentage                         float64
settlement_term                               float64
dtypes: float64(119), object(32)
memory usage: 124.3+ MB
```

how could I get object type colums store in l1=[id,term..] and float64 type in l2=[member_id,loan_amnt...]
thanks for someone who familiar with pandas helping

Answer (score 1):

You can using `select_dtypes`

```
df.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()
```

Or using `dtypes`

```
df.dtypes.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(list)
```

Comment: for df.dtypes.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(list),return TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: for df.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist() ,return TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences